# Is it Possible to remove header from DOJO Grid

Tags: dojox.grid

Is it Possible to remove header from DOJO Grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your css, do this:

```
.dojoxGridMasterHeader { display: none; }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

it is better to specify in which grid you want to remove header, for example by using id of your parent div:

```
#myDiv .dojoxGridHeader {
    display: none;
}
```